# is sequence necessary between cin.clear() and cin.ignore()?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, iostream, cin

Let me show you my source at first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Type >> ";
        cin >> n;

        if (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Not a number" << endl;

            continue;
        }

        if (n % 2)
            cout << "odd";
        else
            cout << "even";

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Well, This code can run without any problems. however, if I swap between cin.clear() and cin.ignore(), then type character(not integer), it stucks in infinite loop. (consult next code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Type >> ";
        cin >> n;

        if (cin.fail()) {               
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cin.clear();
            cout << "Not a number" << endl;

            continue;
        }

        if (n % 2)
            cout << "odd";
        else
            cout << "even";

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wonder sequence is neccesary between cin.clear() and cin.ignore().
if it is, I wanna know why it needs sequence.

Thx for read my Question. I will be very appreciated for any your replies.
sorry for inarticulate Writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the second snippet step by step:

```
if (cin.fail()) {
```

If we enter this, the stream is already bad. So the input operation

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

fails immediately and does nothing. Thus, after

```
cin.clear();
```

the garbage input is still in the stream and makes

```
cin >> n;
```

fail again, without even waiting for input, which gets us back to the beginning.

If you swap the calls around (like in the first snippet), the `clear` will make the stream "good" again, then `ignore` successfully gets rid of the garbage input, and the `cin >> n;` will work as expected.

Comment: Wow, I see. now I know why. Thx!Then, cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n') does not work if cin.failbit is already set, right?

Comment: @ChingChangeatthebaby Correct, after all, it is an input function too.

Answer (score 0):

While `cin.fail()` is true, any attempts to read from the stream will - eh - fail.

Calling `cin.clear()` removes the failure flags from the stream, and thus enables input again.